# Vue 3 (Vite) iframe always loads index.html instead of local html

Tags: html, vue.js, iframe, vue-router

I'm quite new to Vue and I'm trying to embed a local html file into my Vue template using an iframe. I know there are plenty of related questions around, but so far none of the provided solutions fixed my problem.

This is what my component currently looks like:

```
<template>
  <!-- VisTest.html from public folder is used here-->
  <iframe id="myframe" :src="htmlPath"></iframe>
</template>

<script lang="ts">
import { defineComponent } from "vue";

export default defineComponent({
  data() {
    return {
      htmlPath: window.location.origin + "/VisTest.html",
    };
  },
});
</script>
```

The html file to display is located in the `public` folder and the variable `htmlPath` points to the correct location (http://localhost:3000/VisTest.html). When accessing the provided URL directly through the browser, the requested html is served.

However in the actual application, it seems like the iFrame is loading the index.html file as this is the visual output:

[image]

Previoulsy I had the html located in the `src` folder and was addressing it directly via abolute Path, which worked fine in development, but failed when bundling the application of course (again index.html was displayed).

I have played around with various configurations but currently I don't really know where to go from here. Any hints are very much appreciated, thank you in advance! :)

PS: I am using Vue-Router in case this could have something to do with my issue.

Answer (score 0):

Your web server is most likely setup for [HTML5 history mode](https://router.vuejs.org/guide/essentials/history-mode.html). That will always serve the index.html, and let Vue Router handle the actual routing.